# Laravel update pivot timestamps to specific date instead of attach date

Tags: laravel

I have a one to many relationship which is using a pivot table to attach related models.

The standard timestamps are working correctly and the created_at / updated_at are getting populated with the dates when the relationshi gets created or modified.

However, I have a case where I would like to override the timestamps values.

I would like to do something like this :

```
$user->tickets()->attach($ticket->id)
->withTimestamps(['created_at' => '2021-01-01 00:00:01','updated_at' => '2021-01-01 00:00:01']);
```

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: @TimLewis that's the right syntax, might as well just put it as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As confirmed by @N69S, the correct syntax to include or override column values during attach is to pass an associative array of nested columns:

```php
$user->tickets()->attach([
  $ticket->id => [
    'created_at' => '2021-01-01 00:00:01',
    'updated_at' => '2021-01-01 00:00:01'
  ]
]);
```

This should add a record to your pivot table with the correct User ID, Ticket ID and overridden timestamps.

Comment: Thank you both for your help